# Count the record in table

Tags: php

I want to display the countNum in the txt box but it display nothing.

i do something like this.

```
 <input type="text" value="<?php $countNum; ?>" disabled = "disabled">

 <?php
    $countNum = "";
    $Q = mysql_query("select * from  blotterreport");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($Q)) {  

        echo "<tr onclick='trClick()'>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["entrynumber"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["natureofcase"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["month"] . " " . $row["day"] . " " . $row["year"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["subject"] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $countNum++;
    }
                    echo $countNum;
?>
```

Comment: Do you understand that you output `$countNum` __before__ counting?

Comment: That does not work, because at the point where you set `$countNum` there is no value in it? You should use something like ajax to update the value of the textbox after running the PHP script.

Comment: The first `<?php $countNum; ?>` must be `<?php echo $countNum; ?>`

Comment: And also there is `mysql_num_rows()` afair

Comment: thanks for answering this question @u_mulder XD thanks for your time XD

Answer (score 1):

Should use `$countNum = mysql_num_rows($Q);` before `input` text field.

```
<?php 
$Q = mysql_query("select * from  blotterreport");
$countNum = mysql_num_rows($Q);
?>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $countNum; ?>" disabled = "disabled">
<?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($Q)) {  
        echo "<tr onclick='trClick()'>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["entrynumber"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["natureofcase"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["month"] . " " . $row["day"] . " " . $row["year"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["subject"] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
```

Note : Please avoid `mysql_*` function because `mysql_*` function has been deleted permanently from PHP 7. Please use `mysqli_`or `PDO`.

For PDO : http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

For Mysqli : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php

Comment: @digoldy what is the situation now?